# Splitting up multiple sensor data in Azure Stream Analytics from 1 Azure IoT Hub feed

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have multiple temperature sensors messaging in to Azure IoT Hub. Azure IoT Hub then passes this to Azure Stream Analytics which then in turn passes on to Power BI as a streaming dataset for real-time visualization.

The issue is that the Azure Stream Analytics receives all the messages as one stream and ultimately I want to display the temperature of each sensor in a card visual in Power BI. Unfortunately there is no way with the card visual to filter out the sensors I don't want so it has to be done back at Stream Analytics to pass the individual sensors and their result to Power BI. Now I can do this using a WHERE clause and matching each device id but I was wondering if there was a better way as that seems a very cumbersome way to do this especially as we'll be adding up to about 100 sensors and as ones come and go the overhead to manually go back and change each device ID seems very high.

Can anyone assist in providing a better way to do this?

Requirements are that Power BI is the visualization tool and that the visualization is real-time 24 hours as alerts will be set up for each sensor.

Thanks.

Comment: have you considered to put a SQL Database between Stream Analytics and PowerBI? This will also give you data retention and much more flexibility in terms of your analytics queries. The time delay shouldn't be much more than 5-10min if that's acceptable for your solution.

Comment: thanks @silent. Unfortunately that delay will be unacceptable. The experience required is as near time as possible.

Comment: It seems something we should be able to do in Azure Stream Analytics. Can you share some sample data so we can assist you for the query. I also see you need to "manually change each device ID": maybe you may want to have a file used as reference data to dynamically filter data based on a white list of deviceIDs.